# Xamarin / Visual Studio picks core library over specific platform library in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, visual-studio-2019

In my Xamarin solutions the Xamarin.Android project uses the core/standard assembly instead of the platform specific library from the monoandroid90 folder.

I'm using brand new Xamarin solutions templates and the iOS and UWP projects do pick the platform specific nuget assembly.

For AzureAD authentication I use the [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) nuget package. Android needs an extra line of code in 'OnActivityResult' to catch return values, that is implemented in the monoandroid90 version of Microsoft.Identity.Client.

Currently I'm working with an work-around by not using Nuget, but hard referencing each project to each platform specific assembly.

Is there a way to let Xamarin/VisualStudio/Nuget choose platform specific libraries over core/standard .net libraries?

Comment: Using using `MSBuild.Sdk.Extras` when multi-targeting for UWP and Xamarin as it greatly simplifies your project file. Check https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT thanks, i'll check it. Nonetheless it feels like a work-around because Xamarin.Android just should use Android assemblies first before looking for other versions, in my opinion.

Comment: Please tell me the result whether it works or not.